# HREF link not going to output target

Tags: html

I have an href link set to output to target=‘right’. ‘right’ is an I frame in the parent window.

```
<a href=‘http://www.example.com/abc.pup?ev=$ev’ target=‘right’>Click</a>
```

The desired target, ‘right’ is in the parent document. The link is not finding the target. It worked well until I I did some editing.

Answer (score 0):

> The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document:

[image]

You can see details from this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax would be:
`<a href="http://www.example.com/abc.pup?ev=<?php echo $ev; ?>" target="right">Click</a>`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. When the required link href is written in full as http://www.example.com/rqdpage.php the output will be a new window regardless of the target stated, probably for security reasons. The required target is implemented when the required page is in the same directory as the calling page and is stated as a relative path. Thus

```
<a href=‘rqdpage.php?ev=$ev’ target=right></a>
```

worked perfectly. Output in frame “right”. Thanks all.